# Drupal 6: defining js and css for particular pages

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-6, javascript

I'm a drupal newbie...

When I define css and js at **filename.info** file, it takes effects for all pages. I have some particular css-js files for some particular pages, and I don't wanna slow site down by importing all these files for the pages actually no need these files.

How can I define js and css for particular pages?

Appreciate helps!!! thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

The [Drupal API](http://api.drupal.org/) offers two functions [`drupal_add_css`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_add_css/6) and [`drupal_add_js`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_add_js/6) that you can use.

There's a gotcha, if you use these in fx the `preprocess_page` function where the `$script` and `$styles` variable already has been created, you need to overwrite it with, [`drupal_get_css`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_get_css/6) or [`drupal_get_js`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_get_js/6)

Answer (score 0):

You can always add specific JavaScript for a particular content type using the preprocess_node function in template.php of your theme:-

```
function template_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['type'] == 'content_type') { 
    drupal_add_js(path_to_theme() . '/script.js');
  }
}
```

Similarly using drupal_add_css for stylesheets.